# How to fully construct the newly added Entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In my project i need to add Sales leads to the data context. The sales person user adds the leads and I need to send the email to manager for the Lead.

```
    public partial class Lead
{
    public Lead()
    {
        this.LeadActivities = new HashSet<LeadActivity>();
    }

    public long LeadID { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public long CompanyID { get; set; }
    public long ProductID { get; set; }
    public long CreatedByUserID { get; set; }
    public string Remarks { get; set; }
    public LeadStatusEnum StatusID { get; set; }

    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<LeadActivity> LeadActivities { get; set; }
}

    [Serializable]
public partial class Person
{
    public Person()
    {
        this.Contacts = new HashSet<Contact>();
        this.Users = new HashSet<User>();
    }

    public long PersonID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Designation { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Gender { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Title { get; set; }
    public int StatusID { get; set; }
    public string Thumbnail { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

In the above entity, I have property UserID that is associated to Person table through CreatedByUserID. When I add the new lead, by following code, the User field remains null. Do I need to reconstruct it? if yes then how.

> Edit1
>   Entity Creation is done by following code

```
                Entity = new Model.Lead
            {
                CreatedAt = DateTime.Now,
                CreatedByUserID = SessionManagement.GeneralSession.UserDetail.UserID
            };

        Entity.CreatedAt = Convert.ToDateTime(txtTimestamp.Value);
        Entity.CompanyID = Convert.ToInt64(ddlCompany.SelectedValue);
        Entity.CreatedByUserID = Convert.ToInt64(ddlUser.SelectedValue);
        Entity.ProductID = Convert.ToInt64(lstProducts.SelectedValue);
        Entity.Remarks = txtRemarks.Text;
        DataSource.Leads.Add(Entity);
        DataSource.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Show more code: where is that `CreatedByUserID` you mention set? `DataSource.Leads.Add(Entity);`doesn't really show what you are doing with the `Entity`, how do you make it etc?

Comment: Maybe you should also add the User to the context not only the Lead. Entity framework doesn't add the other Entities to the context for you, but depents on the code.

Comment: I have made an edit showing the entity creation. In fact i just populate the CreatedByUserID field. the user id already exists, is there any way to reconstruct with this data?

Answer (score 1):

[Virtual lazy loading only works with proxy instances](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd456855%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).  Since you're explicitly constructing your `Lead` entity, lazy loading of the `User` navigation property after inserting the entity will not work.

Instead, you should use the [`DbSet.Create`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696136(v=vs.113).aspx) method to new up an instance of the derived proxy type.  Then perform your insert, which will attach to the context, and lazy loading will subsequently work.

Alternatively, you can use your existing POCO, perform the insert and then fetch your inserted entity as its proxy from the `DbSet` by using the [`DbSet.Find`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696418(v=vs.113).aspx) method.

You should also check and make sure your foreign key id and navigation properties are correctly mapped, since properties `CreatedByUserID` and `User` would not be automatically associated by convention.